# How to fix error message initial locale not passed to into serversidetranslation next-i18next?

Tags: next.js, vercel, i18next

i am having issue with next-i18next translate at build time when deploying on vercel.
It returns error message "Initial locale argument was not passed into serverSideTranslations"
for my index and dynamic pages.
please see my index.js snippet below

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useTranslation, Trans } from "next-i18next";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";

import { Services } from "../components/Services";
import { Contact } from "../components/contact/Contact";
import { AboutUs } from "../components/AboutUs";
import { Team } from "../components/Team";
import Properties from "../components/property";

const myLoader = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
};
const myLoader2 = ({ src, width, quality }) => {
  return `${src}?w=${width}&q=${quality || 75}`;
};

export default function Home({ locale }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation(locale, "common");
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Services />
        <Properties />
        <AboutUs
          aboutUsText={t("aboutUsText1")}
          aboutUsText1={t("aboutUsText2")}
          aboutUsText2={t("aboutUsText3")}
          aboutUsText3={t("aboutUsText4")}
        />
        <Team teamText1={t("teamText1")} />
        <Contact />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale }) => ({
  props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
  },
});
```

nexti18.config

```
module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  i18n: {
    locales: ["es-ES", "en-US"],
    defaultLocale: "es-ES",
    localeDetection: false,
    reloadOnPrerender: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    react: { useSuspense: false },
  },

  // "pages": {
  //     "*": ["common"],
  //     "/ourServices/conciergerie": ["conciergerie"],
  //     "/ourServices/realEstate": ["realEstate"]
  // }
};
```

can't see where is my mistake, can someone point it out for me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the index.js you have to set the locale to a default language like this

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale = 'es-ES' }) => ({
  props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])),
  },
});
```